# Regex: How To Group The First Line, And Then Another Group With Everything else?

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex that will put the first line in a group, and then everything else in a second group?

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more detailed or give an example?

Comment: What are you doing and what language? You sure you don't need to just read a file line by line, or something simpler like that?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on flavor, something like this should work: `(?-s)(.*)(?s)(.*)`. This matches and captures `(.*)` twice, the first with "single-line" mode switched off, and the second with it switched on. You may even want to anchor the whole pattern within `\A` and `\Z`.

In Java:

```
String text =
    "first line\r" +
    "second line\r\n" +
    "third line etc";
System.out.println(
    text.replaceFirst(
        "(?-s)(.*)(?s)(.*)",
        "FIRST <<<$1>>>\nREST <<<$2>>>"
    )
);
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/RwfAZ)):

```
FIRST <<<first line>>>
REST <<<
second line
third line etc>>>
```

Depending on what you're actually doing (e.g. reading a file line by line), probably much better solution exists.

Comment: The "nice" thing about this is that it doesn't assume what the line separator is. `java.util.regex.Pattern` recognizes many, including some Unicode ones that aren't just combinations of `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.` does not match newline characters if you do not set the dotmatchesall (or singleline) flag, you can simply do

```
(.*)\r\n([\s\S]*)
```

Note that `\r\n` needs to be changed to whatever your files uses for its newline flag. That would be `\n` on Linux or `\r` on Macs (according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

Answer (score 1):

```
/\A([^\n]*)\n(.*)\Z/s
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
^(.*)$([\s\S]*)
```

Comment: Even if you set `s` and `m` flags, the first `()` will match the entire string due to the greedy `*` and the fact that second group can match an empty string.